# Targetting DataTemplate for only on certain views

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate inside a global/shared ResourceDictionary like this which targets a DataType:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type foo:Bar}">
    <!-- My DataTemplate visual tree goes here... -->
</DataTemplate>
```

This DataTemplate replaces my all foo:Bar types on all my Views (UserControls/Windows). What I want to do is to apply this template to only certain views, keeping the other views are not affected by this DataTemplate. I can copy this DataTemplate to Resources sections of each of these view, but I don't want to copy/paste the contents of the DataTemplate which would result in maintenance headaches.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are using here is called [implicit data template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750613.aspx#stylesimplicitkeys). And you are asking for an explicit one. To accomplish this you could use explicit resource key:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyStyle" DataType="{x:Type foo:Bar}">
    <!-- My DataTemplate visual tree goes here... -->
</DataTemplate>
```

And later in xaml:

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{StaticResource MyStyle}" .../>
```

Another solution would be one resource dictionary (with implicit data templates) used via [Merged Dictiories](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx) inside appropriate Control/Page.

I prefer the first approach, because it's easier to maintain (implicit styles are way harder to trace).

Comment: Thanks! Second approach worked for me. I can't use the first approach because I don't have the control of foo:Bar types created, they are 3rd party controls inner types which I am targeting implicitly.